# How to create a preset on Transcoder API

Tags: google-cloud-platform

I am planing to use Transcoder API to encode some videos, according to the documentation, you can pass a preset:

https://cloud.google.com/transcoder/docs/samples/transcoder-create-job-from-preset

However, I couldn't find the list of presets or how to create a new one.

How to create a preset?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Right now google  has one "[preset/web-hd](https://cloud.google.com/transcoder/docs/concepts/overview#job_template)" that is used as a default, it generates SD & HD encoded with h264 & aac and outputs HLS, MPD, mp4. You can create a [custom job template](https://cloud.google.com/transcoder/docs/how-to/job-templates) also.

Below is example of json file:

```
$ cat > request.json << 'EOF'
{
  "inputUri": "gs://STORAGE_BUCKET_NAME/STORAGE_INPUT_VIDEO",
  "outputUri": "gs://STORAGE_BUCKET_NAME/STORAGE_OUTPUT_FOLDER/",
  "templateId": "preset/web-hd"
}
EOF
```

You can find more methods in this [quickstart documentation](https://cloud.google.com/transcoder/docs/transcode-video#create_job).